# MongoDB 3.0.4 Replica SET database level lock while inserting, not able to read other collection?

Tags: mongodb, concurrency, locking, replicaset

I am having a replica set includes (1 primary, 1 secondary and 1 recovering server), I am performing following on primary:

1. All writes and reads are performing on and from primary.
2. Let's say we have one database consisting of 5 collections A, B, C, D and
   E
3. We are performing write (importing or upserting) on  collection
   A, so does it will impact on other collections? Like does mongodb
   allow read operation to collection B and C at the same time?
4. Or it will perform a Write lock to database level, so it will prevent
   other read operation also?
5. List item The problem I am getting at present
   is, I am writing on  collection A it will give timeouts to the other
   READ operation performing on other database?

Please provide a specification with example, it would be great help..

Comment: Are you using mmapv1 or wiredtiger storage engine? MongoDB transactions are atomic at document level with wired tiger storage engine.  Concurrency varies with storage engine..

Comment: Storage engine: mmapv1

Comment: mmapv1 storage engine we are using

Answer (score 1):

With replica sets, when mongodb writes to a collection on the primary say collection A in your case, it also writes data into the primary's `oplog` which syncs data to secondaries. Here, `oplog` collection is a part of `local` database.

So, mongo has to lock both the databases ie., `collection'`s database and the `local` database at the same time to keep the database consistent and ensure that write operations are atomic ie., update all or nothing.

Different mongoDB operations hold different variants of locks. I would suggest you to go through the below link to have good understanding on the locking mechanism and concurrency.

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/concurrency/#mgl-ref

You can check the status of the locks by issuing `db.serverStatus().locks` command. It tells you the different types of locks your mongod has including oplog.

Comment: Thanks for reverting, I have been through this link, I want to confirm, if there is intend exclusive lock on database level i.e. small w (w), does it allow any read operation to that db? What is the difference between small w and capital W, like : "locks" : {
                                "Global" : "w",
                                "MMAPV1Journal" : "w",
                                "Database" : "w",
                                "Collection" : "W"